# Subquery In Postgresql not matching data expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

When the query below is used I get 7 records from the database.

```
SELECT pickup_date::date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN paid ='Yes' THEN price  ELSE 0  END) AS  TotalMoMoPaid 
from requests 
where order_status = 'Done' 
  and payment_mode = 'MoMo' 
  and pickup_date::date >= current_timestamp::date - INTERVAL '7 days' 
GROUP BY pickup_date::date,paid,order_status,price
```

[image]

When the same query is used as a sub query, I get 2 records which is not what I expect,

```
SELECT pickup_date::date,
       sub.TotalMoMoPaid, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN order_status ='Done' THEN price  ELSE 0  END) AS "TotalCashSales" 
from (
  SELECT paid as subPaid,
         order_status as subStatus,
         price as subPrice, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN paid ='Yes' THEN price  ELSE 0  END) AS  TotalMoMoPaid 
  from requests 
  where order_status = 'Done' 
    and payment_mode = 'MoMo' 
    and pickup_date::date >= current_timestamp::date - INTERVAL '7 days' 
  GROUP BY pickup_date::date,subPaid,subStatus,subPrice
) AS sub, requests  
where order_status ='Done' 
  and payment_mode = 'Cash' 
  and pickup_date::date >= current_timestamp::date - INTERVAL '7 days'
GROUP BY sub.TotalMoMoPaid,subPaid,pickup_date::date 
ORDER BY sub.TotalMoMoPaid,pickup_date::date
```

[image]

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  After all, what would you expect from a Cartesian product other than multiplying the number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work instead of using subqueries;

```
SELECT pickup_date::date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_mode = 'MoMo' and paid = 'Yes' THEN price  ELSE 0  END) AS TotalMoMoPaid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_mode = 'Cash' and paid = 'Yes' THEN price  ELSE 0  END) AS TotalCashSales
FROM requests 
WHERE order_status = 'Done' 
      and pickup_date::date >= current_timestamp::date - INTERVAL '7 days' 
GROUP BY pickup_date::date,paid,order_status,price
```

Comment: Ok sure but the query is now bring out data of same dates on different rows, it has to sum up for same dates. check the link below
https://ibb.co/qgJsMg5

Comment: I think payment mode in group by causes this, so i edited the query. Can you try the new version?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it fixed after I removed paid,order_status,price from the GROUP BY